# How to reset the rolling() in Pandas for each index value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm trying to sum each home or away victory of each team of my dataset before each game.

Here is my original dataframe :

```
date              Home     Visitors    Result
2020-01-01        Paris     Lisbon       1
2020-01-03        Madrid    London       0
2020-01-13        Lisbon    Madrid       1
2020-01-14        London    Paris        1
2020-01-16        Lisbon    London       0 
2020-01-18        Paris     Madrid       1 
2020-01-20        Madrid    London       1
```

Result = 1 (home team won)

Result = 0 (visitor team won)

with a `df.set_index('date')[['home', 'result']].groupby(['home', 'date'])['result'].sum()` i got the following output :

```
                        0  1
home      date
Lisbon    2020-01-13    0  1
          2020-01-16    1  0
London    2020-01-03    0  1
Madrid    2020-01-03    1  0
          2020-01-20    0  1
Paris     2020-01-01    0  1
          2020-01-18    0  1
```

My expected result is :

```
                        0  1
home      date
Lisbon    2020-01-13    0  0
          2020-01-16    0  1
London    2020-01-03    0  0
Madrid    2020-01-03    0  0
          2020-01-20    1  0
Paris     2020-01-01    0  0
          2020-01-18    0  1
```

I tried with rolling(), but i do not know how to reset the rolling each `home` index

Any idea ?

Regards

Comment: Could you explain what are the meaning of the 0 and 1 column in the expected result?

Comment: Column 1 mean (home victory) and column 2 mean (visitor victory)

Comment: But what means 0,0? Neither visitor nor home victory? May be a null result but then what represent the values in the initial dataframe?

Comment: if possible i want to have the number of victory home/away of a team before that game. 0, 0 mean the team have still no victory

Answer (score 0):

I think you should restructure your DF, include a column for teams, and instead of putting team names in home/away, put the scores there.

That way, you will be able to group by teams and will be able to sum both the home and away goals separately with the (relatively) new [namedAgg](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html)

If you restructure your DF to something like this

```
DATE     | TEAM     | HOME VICTORY | AWAY VICTORY
01-01-20   ATLETICO        1              0
01-01-20   DORTMUND        0              0
01-02-20   PSG             0              1
01-02-20   PORTO           0              0 
01-10-20   ATLETICO        0              1
01-10-20   PSG             0              1
```

And suppose that the first 2 matches are Atl vs Dor, Atl wins home, then the other matches are PSG Vs Por, PSG wins away, and a third match is Atl vs PSG, Atl wins away.

Your sum function would give you either the victories each team has by date, or, if you forego the date, you could obtain the total wins for the entire tournament.

Group it by Team and date:

```
TEAM     | DATE     | HOME VICTORY | AWAY VICTORY
ATLETICO   01-01-20        1              0
ATLETICO   01-10-20        0              1
PSG        01-02-20        0              1
PSG        01-10-20        0              0
```

Or group it just by team to see their whole performance

```
 TEAM     | HOME VICTORY | AWAY VICTORY
ATLETICO          1              1
PSG               0              1
```

Comment: Column 1 mean (home victory) and column 2 mean (visitor victory) so i do not need score i think. For the second point, if i group by team i will only have the total of home/away win by teams for all championship no ? What i want is the evolution of the total home/away win by team considering the date.

Comment: Sorry, I meant victories, not goals.

I'll edit my answer with a clearer explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I only could do it by duplicating all the rows to have a column indicating away results for teams in the `Home` column. Once this is done, a `cumsum` does the job and we then just need presentation operations to obtain the expected resul:

```
# repeat all lines to build a column away showing for a team its away victories
df2 = pd.concat([df, df[['date', 'Visitors']]
                 .rename(columns = {'Visitors': 'Home'})
                 .assign(away=1-df['Result'])],
                sort=False)

# sum the home and away victories
# and remove the current result from the sum of home victories to only
# keep previous ones
df3 = pd.concat([df2[['date', 'Home', 'Result']], df2.groupby('Home')
                 [['Result', 'away']].cumsum().rename(
                     columns={'Result': 'tot_home'})], axis=1, sort=False
                ).sort_values('date').reset_index(drop=True)

df3['tot_home'] -= df3['Result']

# forward fill by team to "merge" the home and away match results
df4 = df3.groupby('Home').apply(lambda x: x.ffill()).fillna(0).set_index(
    ['Home', 'date']).sort_index().drop(columns='Result')

# finaly get the expected result
df5 = df4.loc[df.set_index(['Home', 'date']).index].sort_index()
```

It gives:

```
                   tot_home  away
Home   date                      
Lisbon 2020-01-13       0.0   0.0
       2020-01-16       1.0   0.0
London 2020-01-14       0.0   1.0
Madrid 2020-01-03       0.0   0.0
       2020-01-20       0.0   0.0
Paris  2020-01-01       0.0   0.0
       2020-01-18       1.0   0.0
```

Remarks:

- I have used different dataframe names (df2-df5) to allow to see all intermediary results. A single df2 could have been used.
- I have not exactly what is given in the question, but I think that the correct values are my ones.